# ngOnInit is not being triggered in dynamically created component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to build Info board. Till the layout was static everything was running fine but when I tried to make the layout dynamic (user can define it) the `ngOnInit` wasn't called in the created components.

I have two main components one where user can select for what building he want's to see the board for (`SelectBoardComponent`) and second that contains the board itself (`BoardComponent`). When I navigate from the `SelectBoardComponent` to the `BoardComponent` everything works. But when I reload or directly access the path for `BoardComponent` whole Angular cycle (OnInit....) is not triggered in the dynamically added childrens.

I have reproduced this issue on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndqfax)

### Code

To be able to find out what component I want to create I have created a "Component registry" where I register every component that could be rendered dynamically.

```
import {Type} from '@angular/core';

type ComponentClass = Type<any>;

const REGISTRY = new Map<string, ComponentClass>();

export const getTypeFor = (name: string): ComponentClass => {
  return REGISTRY.get(name);
};
export const Register = () => {
  return (cls: ComponentClass) => {
    REGISTRY.set(cls.name, cls);
  };
};
```

So I register `InfoCardComponent` one of the components I want to render

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Register} from '../register';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-info-card',
  templateUrl: './info-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./info-card.component.css']
})
@Register()
export class InfoCardComponent implements OnInit {
  public called = "not called!";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.called = "called!";
  }
}
```

In the `BoardComponent` I add `appRender` directive to the element I want to display the components inside

The `appRender` handles the process of generating the components.
I render the components based on JSON data.

```
  private components = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "position": 0,
    "cells": [
      {
        "id": "info",
        "title": "Info panel",
        "component": "InfoCardComponent",
        "childs": []
      }
    ]
  }
];
  private componentsRef = {};

  constructor(
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private injector: Injector,
    private componentFactory: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = '';
      const {rows} = this.render();
      for (const row of rows) {
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, row);
      }
  }

  render() {
    const grid = {rows: []};
    for (const c of this.components) {
      const cells = c.cells;
      if (cells.length > 0) {
        const row = this.renderer.createElement('div');
        for (const {component} of cells) {
          const cell = this.renderer.createElement('div');
          const card = this.renderer.createElement('div');
          this.renderer.appendChild(card, this.createAngularComponent(component).elem);
          this.renderer.appendChild(cell, card);
          this.renderer.appendChild(row, cell);
        }
        grid.rows.push(row);
      }
    }
    return grid;
  }
  private createAngularComponent(parentComponent) {
    const componentElem = this.componentFactory.resolveComponentFactory(getTypeFor(parentComponent)).create(this.injector);
    this.componentsRef[parentComponent] = componentElem;
    this.appRef.attachView(componentElem.hostView);
    return {
      elem: (componentElem.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement,
    };
  }
```

### So my question is:

Is this an expected behavior or I forgot something?

I would be glad for any help.

Comment: In my application ngOnInit is being called but ngAfterViewInit is not being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an LifeCycleHook problem. You can't access ElementRef's and TemplateRef's in `ngOnInit()`, because the template is not yet rendered. You should use `ngAfterViewInit()` LifeCycleHook. Move your logic from `ngOnInit()` to `ngAfterViewInit()`.

What to do:

Change `ngOnInit()` to `ngAfterViewInit()`:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = '';
        const {rows} = this.render();
        for (const row of rows) {
          this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, row);
        }
      }, 0)
  }
```

`setTimeout()` is for fixing ExpressionHasBeenChanged-Error.

Don't forget to implement `AfterViewInit` and to import that from `@angular/core`

Comment: In my project I am calling it inside of `AfterViewChecked` why is the timeout also necessary there?

Comment: @JosefKatič It is an ChangeDatection problem. In this article you will find more explanation and infos about that error and fix possibilities: https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Comment: For me the timeout will prevent the dynamic component from rendering.