# ngoninit not working on dynamically component

Tags: angular, ngoninit

I tried to created dynamically  component for reporting, which is i got the tutorial from this link :

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Dynamic component is already load, but ngOnInit is not working, i had explorer many way such as :

- [ngOnInit is not being triggered in dynamically created component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55660594/ngoninit-is-not-being-triggered-in-dynamically-created-component)

But still not solve my problem.

Here is my code :

**item class**

```
export class ReportItem {
  constructor(public component: Type<any>, public data: any) {}
}
```

**inteface**

```
export interface ReportComponent {
    data: any;
  }
```

**directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[reporting]',
})
export class ReportDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

**html**

```
<section id="reporting-contener">
  <ng-template reporting></ng-template>
</section>
```

**ts to create dynamic component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-reporting',
  templateUrl: './reporting.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reporting.component.scss']
})
export class ReportingComponent implements OnInit {
 reports: ReportItem = null;
  @ViewChild(ReportDirective) reportHost: ReportDirective;
  backTo:Boolean = false;
  reportName:string = ""
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router:Router,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private reportservice:ReportService,
    private gm:GeneralMethod,
  ) { 

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.reportName = params['reportName']
      this.reports = this.reportservice.getReports(this.reportName);
      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        if(!this.gm.isObjectEmpty(params)){

          this.reports.data= params;

        }else{

          this.backTo = true;
        }
      });

    });

  }
  componentRef = null
  ngOnInit(){
    if(this.backTo ){
      //this.router.navigate["transaction"]
    }

    const reportItem = this.reports;

    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(reportItem.component);
    const viewContainerRef = this.reportHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<ReportComponent>this.componentRef.instance).data = reportItem.data;
    this.componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.componentRef.destroy(); 
   }
}
```

Code for dynamic component :

**HTML**

```
<div>
    Test :  {{data.test}} Testing : {{data.testing}}
</div>
```

**ts**

```
export class ReportingTesting implements ReportComponent, OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() data: any;

  testing = "100" //not working
  constructor(){ //not working
    this.testing = "Test call on constructor"
  }
  ngOnInit(){ //not working
    this.testing = "Test call on ngoninit"
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){ //not working
    this.testing = "Test call on ngAfterViewInit"
  }
}
```

**services**

```
@Injectable()

export class ReportService {
  getReports(reportName:string) {
    let lsReport = [];
    lsReport["test"] = new ReportItem(ReportingTesting, {});

    return lsReport[reportName];
  }
}
```

**Route navigate**

```
this.router.navigate(['/report/test'], { queryParams: {'test':"Test Param", route:""}});
```

The Result when i call the component :

[image]

Result should be :

```
//constructor
Test : Test Param Testing : Test call on constructor

//ngOnInit
Test : Test Param Testing : Test call on ngoninit

//ngAfterViewInit
Test : Test Param Testing : Test call on ngAfterViewInit
```

Am I forgot something?
I would be glad for any help.

Comment: isn't data.testing different from the testing in your ts?

Comment: @Ramesh: Thanks... that must be testing... my mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing value of `this.testing` and displaying `data.testing` so it appears to you that `constructor` and `ngOnInit` are not working so if you want to display `this.testing` try this:

```
<div>
    Test :  {{data.test}} Testing : {{testing}}
</div>
```